# Почему не работает арифметическое выражение?

Tags: c

Вроде всё правильно...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b; 
while (1)
{
 int a,b,c;
 printf ("Введите 3 целых числа: ");
 scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
 printf("%d / %d * %d = %g\n%d * %d /%d = %g\n\n",a,b,c,a/b*c,a,b,c,a*b/c);
 getchar();
}
}
```

Однако:
[image: баг.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Целочисленное деление не дает чисел с плавающей точкой, выполняя деление нацело с отбрасыванием дробной части.

Так что замените `%g` на `%d`, или числа на `double` вместо `int`.

Или хотя бы вычисляйте как `double(a)/b*c`

Comment: Мне только показалось или у автора вопроса и нет деления дробного? просто ответ выводится в виде float(или double) чего автор понять не может... а все деления со скриншота - и так целочисленные ответы дадут =) просто для начала формат вывода надо поправить

Comment: Да, тут для не программиста явно парадокс. Хотя с точки зрения языка программирования объясняется легко.

Answer (score 2):

Арифметическое выражение у вас работает прекрасно. "Не работает" у вас именно `printf`.

Выражение `a/b*c` порождает результат типа `int`, а вы в `printf` указали формат `%g`, который требует аргумента типа `double`. Несоответствие формата и фактического типа аргумента в `printf` - неопределенное поведение. Именно это вы и наблюдаете.

Определитесь, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Если вы хотели использовать целочисленное деление, то формат должен быть `%d`. Если вы хотели использовать плавающее деление, что вычислять надо `(double) a / b * c`.